# Tkinter Entry widget insertwidth

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

i'm new in tkinter so I need some help with the tkinter's Entry widget.

I'm stuck on the `insertborderwidth` and `insertwidth` option. My code is....

```
root = tk.Tk()

root.geometry("300x350")

Label1 = tk.Label(root, text="insertborderwidth ").grid(row=0, column=0)
Entry1 = tk.Entry(root , insertborderwidth = tk.RAISED , insertwidth=2).grid(row=0, column=1,padx=15 , pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

and the error is:

[The error is showing in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BjbBN.png)

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I m new to Tkinter and I'm trying to practice all the functions available in Tkinter. I'm doing good for most of the functions and classes but sometimes I stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this solve your issue? (Changed `insertborderwidth` to a number and added  `relief ='raised'`)

```
Entry1 = tk.Entry(root , insertborderwidth = 8, relief ='raised', insertwidth=2).grid(row=0, column=1,padx=15 , pady=20)
```